# Is my HDD partially healing itself?

Tags: hard-drive, smart, overheating

I have a disk with a raw value of ~20000 for S.M.A.R.T.'s `Raw Read Error Rate` and a worst value for `Temperature (Celsius)`of 95. I ran `gddrescue` 1.17 multiple times and diffed the `ddrescue` log files. Files of newer runs contain less and less error entries than the preceeding ones, some entries contain different values, but there're no new entries in newer log files.

Is that a reliable indicator for the disk partially healing itself? I assume there're sectors which won't heal, but that's not part of my question.

Comment: This might be causing the drive's spare sector pool to replace bad sectors it is finding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. Like mdpc pointed out in his_her comment bad sectors are replaced from the drive's spare pool. GNU `ddrescue` even enforces this healing process after reading the input device completely (as well as it is possible) and you can watch the error count decrease.